# is it possible to download a file in my iphone throuh email

Tags: iphone, file, data-transfer

I am working on an application in which i write to an xml file and then send it through email and at the reciever end the receiver recives it in his/her inbox and download the file to the iphone and then open the same app on his phone and browse to this file and by clicking sync button the progra should parse the tags in the xml file.
Everything is cler but i am not sure whether we can download a file to our iphone and browse thru it our app.

Thanks, i appreciate. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I don't believe you can download a file from mail and pass it to your app to open and read. This would be for security reasons.

I think the only way to achieve this would be to not use an XML file, and instead construct a URL with parameters.

There are a few drawbacks here, though. Depending on how much data you need to pass, the url could get pretty large. You would have to take considerations to make sure that each parameter value is properly URL escaped. And you could have to write code to parse the data in the parameters.

This is how other apps pass data between apps, an example would be the iPhone's Phone app. You can make it call a number by using a `tel://` URL.

You can register a URL scheme in your app and use it to pass data around.

Comment: The app is all abput sending the data (map, pictures and text) through email and then open it at the receiver end if we suppose that user also has the same application.

Comment: Then that isn't possible using email. You may have better results using a back end server solution.

Comment: Ya but the basic requirement of this application is it should be using limited resources. please let me know if you have some innovative idea.